Graylog All Messages widget settings
I am using Graylog version 6.1.1. Whenever I perform any action that takes me to the Search (not pre-saved), the "All Messages" widget always displays the columns "timestamp" and "source". I would like the "level" column to also be displayed by default. Is there any way to configure this? Currently, I have to manually add it each time, for example, when I use the "Show surrounding messages" command.
